# The time-derivative of the Hamiltonian for a 1D harmonic potential

Tags: derivatives, operator-algebras, harmonic-functions, quantum-mechanics

I do not undersand how to take the time derivative of the following Hamiltonian  $\hat{H}(t) = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(\hat{x}-a(t))^2$ where $a(t) = v_0t$. For instance how does $\hat{p}$ change when taking the time derivative of it? And the same for $\hat{x}$.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture#Mathematical_details

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written it, without time arguments in $\hat p$ and $\hat x$, these two operators are presumed to be in the Schrödinger   representation, i.e.,  *time independent*. Thus
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \hat H(t)=\partial_t \hat H(t)=v_0(v_0 t-\hat x).
$$

Note this is not the [Galilean transform](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341242/why-the-galileo-transformation-are-written-like-this-in-quantum-mechanics) of the oscillator hamiltonian, but, instead, a Hamiltonian canonically equivalent  to the $v_0=0$ case, and with the same spectrum as it. (Under a quantum canonical transformation, the commutation relations are preserved.)

It would be perverse &  unfriendly to assume your expression is  in the Heisenberg picture while omitting the (t), as the Schrödinger operator above would have to be converted into the corresponding Heisenberg one, $U(t)^\dagger v_0(v_0 t-\hat x) U(t)$, liable to [confuse you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture#Mathematical_details), if you are asking this question.